# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when I run this Interop code with word

Tags: c#, vb.net, office-interop

When I run this code to take the text off a word document it ends with multiple System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException 's

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If Origcv = "" Then
        Label10.Text = "Select a CV"
    Else
        ' Create application instance.
        Dim app As Application = New Application

        ' Open specified file.
        Dim doc As Document = app.Documents.Open(Origcv)

        ' Loop through all words.
        Dim count As Integer = doc.Words.Count
        Dim cvw(count) As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To count
            ' Write word to screen.
            Dim text As String = doc.Words(i).Text

            cvw(i) = doc.Words(i).Text
        Next
        ' Quit the application.
        app.Quit()
```

The errors all come on the doc.words(I).text even though the .count has succeeded. I have installed all components of word and .net and still can't get this to work. I used to have it working fine when I used the same code before on my laptop before it was factory reset so I assume I am missing some kind of component or setting, the interop.word reference is recognized and has the file path on the references tab. Any help here need to get this finished quickly and this is literally the first hurdle.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Without more information about the exact error(s) being thrown it's not possible to know what the problem is. Put your code in a Try...Catch block and capture the Exception.Message. Office doesn't pass all error message back to .NET without Try...Catch, so that may provide more useful information. Also, be careful with your String array: in the .NET Framework these are zero-based and you're starting at 1 (which is correct for doc.Words, but not for a .NET array). And in the last loop the subscript will be out of range.

Comment: error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM Component

Comment: I have tried re adding the reference - i have also now added any reference that might pertain to accessing words features, i have installed PIA for interop with word. Re installed word with all features, I cant guarantee that the word document will have no tab characters as i have no control over their creation- but i have mad my own test document with no tabs at all and i think it is not the issue. I have tried changing the target framework to net 2.0 but that returns the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is `Dim app As Application = New Application` This kind of construct is always dangerous. Many namespaces use `Application` - you have no qualifier that tells .NET which application is meant. The fact that Documents.Open works could also be because the namespace .NET is referencing also has a Documents class.

If you fully qualify it:

```
Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
```

I believe the problem will go away.

If it does, put an `Imports` at the top of the module that assigns an Alias to the namespace then use the Alias to qualify objects in the Word namespace (makes things shorter):

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Then

```
Dim app as Word.Application = New Word.Application()
Dim doc as Word.Document = app.Documents.Open(Origcv)
```

Comment: Unfortunately still the  
'error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM Component' i am starting to think this is becasue i am missing a redist or because the permissions are stopping it. All of the interop features are listed on the drop down errors. I have no idea why it was working before and now it is not, the only thing i can think is that i was using a different version of visual studio.

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe this is happening because i have literally just dragged my project directory to my back up drive and then copied it back over on a factory reset. I will try to create a new project and re do it.

Comment: just created an new project and the same issue occurs when i run this code. I think it must be something wrong with actual system.

Comment: You could try repairing Office and Visual Studio.